# Search by the part of 'id' in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have json objects, something like this:

```
{"id":"one","name":"John"}
{"id":"two","name":"Steve"}
```

I put them into Elasticsearch with `index="people"`, `type="user"`, `id=/document id(one, two)/`.
    The task is to find this objects by the part of id (for example, "ne" or "wo").
    I am using elasticsearch 6.2.4 with rest high level client

Maybe somebody knows how to do this searching in the best way?

Here is code sample, I've tried:

```
  SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder(); 
    sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.termQuery("id", partOfId)); 
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(index); 
    searchRequest.types(type); searchRequest.indices("id").source(sourceBuilder);
    SearchResponse searchResponse;
    try (RestHighLevelClient client = getClient()){
     searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest); 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(INCORRECT_PARAMS);
 }
```

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question instead of adding it as a comment. Thanks

Comment: Check this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

Comment: I can use ElasticSearch only in Java code and would like to know, how can I do this task in Java